# Add Shadow/Border to the Drawn path - GLPaint

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ios5, xcode4.2

Currently i am working on a drawing app based on GLPaint . I want to add a shadow effect (or border) to the drawn path . Does anybody have experience with it? Currently I am working on OpenGL ES 1.1. Should I have a look on OpenGL ES 2.0 or is it achievable with OpenGL ES 1.1?

I have tried with `glTexImage2D` enabling the width to 1. But the output is a square texture. What should the size of the texture image be? is it 64x64 or 66x66 or something else?